# Clipping vs Filtering Images with a Polygon - Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-fusion-tables, google-earth-engine

I need to analyze the area defined by a polygon that I drew (call it 'X') of the images of Modis Terrra. What is the difference between filtering bounds and clipping to define the area of interest?

I'm confused about the following alternatives:

option 1.

```js
var areaofinterest=ee.ImageCollection('NASA/OCEANDATA/MODIS-Aqua/L3SMI');
    .filterBounds(X)
```

or
option 2.

```js
var aux=ee.ImageCollection('NASA/OCEANDATA/MODIS-Aqua/L3SMI');
var areaofinterest=aux.clip(X);
```

The main question is: what are the differences between the two methods?

- When I do option 1 and then `Map.AddLayer(areaofinterest)` I don't get displayed the area of interest, but the map of the product over the whole world - so I guess something is wrong.
- When I do option 2 I get the error: `aux.clip is not a function in <global>`

Comment: Hi, I see you're new to SO. If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep users focused on answer questions which still don't have accepted answers.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Clip sets the mask of the image outside the geometry with which you're clipping to zero.  Note that `clip()` is a [function on images](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/api_docs#eeimageclip) (NOT image collections).  On the other hand, `filterBounds()` passes elements of the input collection that have geometries intersecting the geometry with which you're clipping.  If the images in the collection are global composites (e.g. MODIS images), then `filterBounds()` won't do anything.

Comment: Thank you Nicholas, for some reason my question was put on hold as too broad by the community manager, but your answer makes it clearer. I am indeed using MODIS and that might be why I'm not getting anything. If clip() is not a function of image collections - how can I do the clipping for an image collection?

Comment: imageCollection.map(function(image) { return image.clip(geometry); });

Comment: How do I know if the images in the collection are "global composites"? I am extracting Sentinel 2 images using (python) 

```
s2_image_collection = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2_SR")
```

Does that return images that are global composites?

Comment: You could add `image.geometry()` to the map or inspect the coordinates in the `system:footprint` property.

Answer (score 0):

It's true that `filterBounds()` won't do anything to a MODIS imageCollection. Only `clip()` works with the individual images inside the collection by a function, `imageCollection.map(function(image) { return image.clip(geometry); })`, which has been presented by Nick.