# Google Earth Engine - filter landsat by cloud cover over multiple polygons

Tags: landsat, google-earth-engine, cloud-cover

I want to make a Landsat image collection that is totally cloud free over a SET of polygons. I have about 300 polygons (all within a single Landsat tile). I found [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/252685/filter-landsat-images-base-on-cloud-cover-over-a-region-of-interest) question, which is doing exactly what I want over a single polygon, but I can't figure out how to get it to work over a set of polygons (which are loaded as a feature class).

Here is what I tried to do to modify the solution from the question posted above, where imgcollection is my Landsat TOA Image Collection and fc is my feature class of polygons. I was trying to use map and clip together to select all the polygons in the feature class for each image (based on the answers in [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/247955/clipping-vs-filtering-images-with-a-polygon-google-earth-engine/247959#247959) related question).

```js
  var combine = imgcollection.map(function(imgcollection) { return 
    imgcollection.clip(fc); });
```

After this line, I tried to continue with the solution from the first question, but it doesn't work.
The error I get is as follows, which confuses me. I'm trying to use the variable "combine" as the geometry - am I misunderstanding this and actually using something else?

```js
  ImageCollection (Error)
  Image.reduceRegion, argument 'geometry': Invalid type. Expected: 
  Geometry. Actual: ImageCollection.
```

EDIT: full code

```js
  var fc = ee.FeatureCollection('ft:omit');

  var imgcollection = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_RT_TOA");

  var combine = imgcollection.map(function(img) { return img.clip(fc); });

  var withCloudiness = combine.map(function(image) {
    var cloud =       ee.Algorithms.Landsat.simpleCloudScore(image).select('cloud');
    var cloudiness = cloud.reduceRegion({
      reducer: 'mean', 
      geometry: combine, 
      scale: 30,
    });
    return image.set(cloudiness);
  });

  var filteredCollection = withCloudiness.filter(ee.Filter.lt('cloud', 10));
  print(filteredCollection);
```

Comment: you should show the whole script, or at least share a link to it. The error doesn't seem to be related to the code you showed, which has an error too. Argument of a mapping function over `ImageCollection` must be an `Image`. Should be: `var combine = imgcollection.map(function(img) { return img.clip(fc); });`

Comment: Thanks, you're right, I fixed that but the error is still there. I posted the full code above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is quite clear. Parameter `geometry` of function `reduceRegion` must be a `Geometry`. In the documentation says:

> *geometry (Geometry, default: null):*
>   The region over which to reduce data. Defaults to the footprint of the image's first band.

So, if you want to reduce over `fc`:

```js
var fc = ee.FeatureCollection('ft:omit');

  var imgcollection = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_RT_TOA");

  var combine = imgcollection.map(function(img) { return img.clip(fc); });

  var withCloudiness = combine.map(function(image) {
    var cloud =       ee.Algorithms.Landsat.simpleCloudScore(image).select('cloud');
    var cloudiness = cloud.reduceRegion({
      reducer: 'mean', 
      geometry: fc.geometry(), 
      scale: 30,
      maxPixels: 1e13,
    });
    return image.set(cloudiness);
  });

  var filteredCollection = withCloudiness.filter(ee.Filter.lt('cloud', 10));
  print(filteredCollection);
```

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, thanks so much! The only issue I am running into now is that I get a time out error when I ask it to print. In reading the developers documentation, I know that 'export to drive' is a way to get around this. But, I only know of an option to export one image, not a collection. Do you know if there's a way to get around this?

Comment: Ser https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/276604/23470

Comment: Thank you! I realized I was trying to download the entire set of landsat images - when I was running it over the entire image collection, the computation timed out still. I selected the dates and  path/row I needed to narrow it down and it ran perfectly.