# GEE: projection error when exporting data to a table

Tags: google-earth-engine, javascript, remote-sensing, ndvi, modis

I am trying to export some vegetation condition index data calculated from MODIS data on Google Earth Engine to a table, but keep getting the error:

```
Error in map(ID=3): Image.reduceRegions: Unable to transform geometry into projection <Projection>
```

This is the code I am using. The error seems to be occurring where I am exporting the data to a table (the lines at the end of this code block), as the rest of the code works well. The variable "mariupol" is a shapefile feature I uploaded to GEE and is in WGS 84 projection

```
Map.addLayer(mariupol);
//
//calculate average monthly NDVI for Mariupol
//get MODIS NDVI
var collection = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MOD13A1').select('NDVI');

// Reference period for baseline NDVI
var reference = ee.ImageCollection(collection.filterDate('2001-01-01', '2020-12-31'))
  .sort('system:time_start');
print("reference",reference);

//filter out images from march, april, may (spring)
var spring = reference.filter(ee.Filter.dayOfYear(59,150));

//calulate min of full series (mam 2001-2020) for each pixel
var spring_min = spring.min();

//calculate max of full series (mam 2001-2020) for each pixel
var spring_max = spring.max();

var vci_bot = spring_max.subtract(spring_min);

//iterate through months and calculate average Vegetation condition Index
var years = ee.List.sequence(2001, 2020);
print("years",years);

var byYear = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(
      years.map(function (y) {
        return spring.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(y, y, 'year'))
                    .select(("NDVI")).mean()
                    .subtract(spring_min)
                    .divide(vci_bot)
                    .set('year', y);
}));
print("byYear",byYear);

//Define chart parameters
var chartParam = {
 title: 'Average VCI (spring), mariupol',
  hAxis: {title: 'Time'},
  vAxis: {title: 'Average VCI'},
};

//Plot the chart
var chart = ui.Chart.image.seriesByRegion({
  imageCollection: byYear,
  regions: mariupol.getInfo(),
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
  scale: 500,
  xProperty: 'year',
  seriesProperty: 'PROJECT'
});
//Print chart to console
print(chart.setOptions(chartParam));

var spring_vci_mariupol = byYear.filterBounds(mariupol);

//get means as table and add to Drive
var spring_vci_means = byYear.map(function(image){
  return image.reduceRegions({
    collection:spring_vci_mariupol,
    reducer:ee.Reducer.mean(), 
    scale: 30
  });
});
var table2 = spring_vci_means.flatten();
print(table2);
Export.table.toDrive(table2,"spring_vci_means_mariupol");
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be related to this line:

```
var spring_vci_mariupol = byYear.filterBounds(mariupol);
```

*.filterBounds()* expects a Geometry, not FeatureCollection, so try to change it accordingly:

```
var spring_vci_mariupol = byYear.filterBounds(mariupol.geometry());
```

I am also wondering what you want to achieve here? *byYear* seems to be a global ImageCollection, so *filterBounds()* won't lead to any changes - maybe you want to clip it instead? [Here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/247955/clipping-vs-filtering-images-with-a-polygon-google-earth-engine) you can find a related post.

If you would share a public link to your script and the imported Shapefile, it would also be easier to inspect the script/outputs :)